# Proving that the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is indeed a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Every element in the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ of the rational numbers can be written in the form $\alpha+\beta\sqrt{2}$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Q}$. The book states that this, like $\mathbb{Q}$, is a field, but that if $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$ then this is no longer true. I guess the last statement can be proven by considering that the multiplicative inverse of $\alpha+\beta\sqrt{2}$ is not an integer, but how can it be proven that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$  is a field when $\alpha,\beta$ are rationals?

Comment: You need to show (or justify) each field axiom is true, in one way or another.

Comment: What properties should an algebra have to be a field? Have you tried to check those?

Comment: You can try to show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \cong \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2-2)$ and that the second is a field, which is equivalent to showing that $(X^2-2)$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: I thought that there would be a more concise way of showing it than going through all of the axioms, but yes that would be a way of showing it.

Comment: Something like what @M.Wang is proposing

Comment: @Jacob Well, if you already know it's a group under addition, or a ring, then you can skip a lot of steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

You only have to prove that  $(\alpha +\beta\sqrt 2)^{-1},\enspace\alpha, \beta\in\mathbf Q\,$ can be written as  $(\gamma +\delta\sqrt 2),\enspace\gamma, \delta\in\mathbf Q$. Use the conjugate:
$$\frac1{\alpha +\beta\sqrt 2}=\frac{\alpha -\beta\sqrt 2}{(\alpha +\beta\sqrt 2)(\alpha -\beta\sqrt 2)}.$$

Comment: I think that you added a ${}^{-1}$ too much.

Comment: @md2perpe: That's right. I  really should re-read before posting; Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: To be fully convincing, I suppose one needs the remark that $\alpha^2-2\beta^2$ can’t be zero for rational $\alpha$, $\beta$ unless both are zero.

Comment: @Lubin: That is basic since $\sqrt2 $ is irrational.

Comment: Just so, @Bernard.

Comment: So by this I prove that there is a multiplicative inverse, such that $(\alpha+\beta \sqrt(2))(\alpha+\beta \sqrt(2))^{-1}=1$, which is what the integers are missing to be a field?

Comment: Yes, since the other ring properties are obviously inherited from $\mathbf Q[\sqrt 2]$,, which is a homomorphic image of the ring of polynomials $\mathbf Q[X]$.

Comment: Great, thank you.